# batch file: pass parameter with white spaces to function

Tags: windows, batch-file, spaces

I am using a batch file for backups. I pass the options to a function which calls the packaging executable. This works unless the parameters contain whitespaces. This is the relevant code:

```
SET TARGET="%SAVEDIR%\XP.User.Documents.rar"
SET FILES="%DIRUSER%\Eigene Dateien\*"      
SET EXLUCDE="%DIRUSER%\Documents\CDs" 
call:funcBackup %TARGET% %FILES% %EXLUCDE%

:funcBackup
    SET TARGET=%~1
    SET FILES=%~2
    SET EXCLUDE=%~3     
    echo."%PACKER% a -r -x"%EXCLUDE%" "%TARGET%" "%FILES%""
    ::call %PACKER% a -r -x"%EXCLUDE%" "%TARGET%" "%FILES%"
goto:eof
```

On XP(german version) %DIRUSER% expands to "Dokumente und Einstellungen"

In that case TARGET is correct, but FILES == "Dokumente" and EXCLUDE == "und",
which means that the script fails because of the whitespaces in %DIRUSER%.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be your style of assigning the variables.
I suppose you set the DIRUSER variable like the other ones

```
set DIRUSER="Dokumente und Einstellungen"
```

But the content of DIRUSER is then `"Dokumente und Einstellungen"`, so the quotes are a part of the content.

But then `SET FILES="%DIRUSER%\Eigene Dateien\*"` expands to `SET FILES=""Dokumente und Einstellungen"\Eigene Dateien\*"`.

You could use the extended style of `set`.
`set "var=content"`
This sets the content of `var` to `content` without any quotes and also all appended spaces behind the last quote are ignored.

So your code would be

```
set "SAVEDIR=D:\backup"
set "diruser=Dokumente und Einstellungen"
SET "TARGET=%SAVEDIR%\XP.User.Documents.rar"
SET "FILES=%DIRUSER%\Eigene Dateien\*"      
SET "EXLUCDE=%DIRUSER%\Documents\CDs" 
call:funcBackup "%TARGET%" "%FILES%" "%EXLUCDE%"
goto :eof

:funcBackup
    SET "TARGET=%~1"
    SET "FILES=%~2"
    SET "EXCLUDE=%~3"
    echo."%PACKER% a -r -x"%EXCLUDE%" "%TARGET%" "%FILES%"
    ::call %PACKER% a
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3):

Switching your arg calls in the function from `%~1`, `%~2` and `%~3` to `%~f1`, `%~f2` and `%~f3` respectively should do the trick. It'll pass the fully qualified path name for each arg.

More info: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/server-management/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-batch-file-